# Alternative for rich:page component in primefaces UI

Tags: primefaces, richfaces

I am working on a Migrating project in PrimeFaces 5.1.

The project is already done in rich faces. In our previous project we use Rich:page component for a page. I need a alternative component in PrimeFaces 5.1 UI.
Kindly help me over it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple to answer. There is none. But if you use a facelets templating mechanism with defines for title etc, there is no real need for such a component in my bit so humbl opinion

Comment: Thanks Dude... But in my concept i need to include 4 or more pages in a single form which is my main page.. how could i use this mechanism with the template components..

Comment: Show what you did in richfaces…  make the examples minimalistic (remove all non relevant tags)

Comment: I will show what i did in rich faces:<rich:page id="sscmsMainRichPage">                                                                        ................                                                                                                   <rich:layout>
<rich:layoutPanel position="center" width="70*">......</rich:layoutPanel></rich:layout> </rich:page>

Comment: Please add this to your question so it is better formatted. And explain why the page tag is so important in relation to the inclusion of 4 pages like described above.

Comment: Maybe p:layout but in modern web, layout should be created using pure CSS. If you are migrating from RichFaces consider a layout css framework like bootstrap, zend, PF Grid css or PrimeFaces Sentinel, Spark etc. Looking at docs of rich:page, it is way too much scary abstraction from html. https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_page.html